# merging two dataframes pandas with agg option on multiple columns at once

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have a question about merging two dataframes.

df1:

```
CDR3    number
ASSADSPYEQY 0
ASSQDSPYEQY 0
ASSADSPYEQY 1
ASSYDSPYEQY 0
ASSADSPYEQY 3
```

df2:

```
seq origine pep protein clonecount  clonefraction
ASSADSPYEQY database    KAYNVTQAF   nucleocapsid phosphoprotein [Severe acute respiratory syndrome coronavirus 2]   12  0.0001
ASSQDSPYEQY database    VQELYSPIFLIV    ORF7a protein [Severe acute respiratory syndrome coronavirus 2] 14  0.02
ASSADSPYEQY sample  KPLEFGATSAAL    orf1ab polyprotein [Severe acute respiratory syndrome coronavirus 2]    122 0.0002
ASSYDSPYEQY sample  SEHDYQIGGYTEKW  ORF3a protein [Severe acute respiratory syndrome coronavirus 2] 111 0.03
ASSADSPYEQY sample  SEHDYQIGGYTEKW  ORF3a protein [Severe acute respiratory syndrome coronavirus 2] 1021    0.004
```

Desired output:

```
seq     origin  pep clonecount  clonefraction   number
ASSADSPYEQY database,sample,sample  KAYNVTQAF,KPLEFGATSAAL,SEHDYQIGGYTEKW   12,122,1021 0.0001,0.0002,0.004 0,1,3
ASSQDSPYEQY database    VQELYSPIFLIV    14  0.0002  0
ASSADSPYEQY sample,database,sample  KAYNVTQAF,KPLEFGATSAAL,SEHDYQIGGYTEKW   12,122,1021 0.0001,0.0002,0.004 0,1,3
ASSYDSPYEQY sample  SEHDYQIGGYTEKW  111 0.003   0
ASSADSPYEQY sample,sample,database  KAYNVTQAF,KPLEFGATSAAL,SEHDYQIGGYTEKW   12,122,1021 0.0001,0.0002,0.004 0,1,3
```

What I've tried:

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2.groupby('seq',as_index=False)[['origin']].agg(','.join),how='left')
```

Ouput I got:

```
seq     origin
ASSADSPYEQY database,sample,sample
ASSQDSPYEQY database
ASSADSPYEQY sample,database,sample
ASSYDSPYEQY sample
ASSADSPYEQY sample,sample,database
```

But I don't know how to add the other columns in the same way... Is this possible at all? Thanks in advance.